# The Expected value for this continuous random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

$$
F(y) = \begin{cases}
    0 & y < 1 \\
    1-y^{-3} & y \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
    0 & x < 1 \\
    3x^{-4} & x \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$

(Original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYhnW.png)

I am trying to find the expected value of X, I know there is some rule for CRV and I believe that the expected value is either the exponent for the CDF which is $-3$ or it is either the exponent for the PDF which is $-4$, some explanation as to why this is would be very helpful, thank you in advance!

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to use a specific "rule", it is here simpler and more natural to use the definition and compute the expected value directly.

That is
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} xf(x)dx
= 3\int_{1}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^3}
= 3\left[-\frac{1}{2x^2}\right]^\infty_1
= \frac{3}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find the expected value of X, I know there is some rule for CRV and I believe that the expected value is either the exponent for the CDF which is −3 or it is either the exponent for the PDF which is −4, some explanation as to why this is would be very helpful, thank you in advance!

An expected value is *determined* by the parameters of a distribution, but not necessarily equal to them.   A well-known family of distributions will have a well known formula to use, but this isn't one of those.

So when in doubt, we go back to the basics and work it out.

$$\mathsf E(X)~{ = \int_\Bbb R x\,f_{\small X}(x)\,\mathrm d x\\ =\int_1^\infty 3x^{-3}\,\mathrm d x} $$